# What is an "avant-loge"?

Tags: vocabulaire

In Douglas Smith's translation of Konstantin Paustovsky's "The Story of a Life", there appears the sentence, in a chapter about an assassination in a theatre, "The imperial box was empty; Nicholas and the rest of the royal family had moved to the *avant-loge*."

"Avant-loge" appears neither in the (real) OED (not Google's version of it), nor in Robert. Could anyone say where the Czar and his entourage moved to?

Comment: Indeed the word as such cannot be found in dictionaries. It would be a space between the corridor and the actual box where the spectators seat, separated from the box by a curtain (or an actual door).  I don't think all boxes have such an area. Whoever was in the avant-loge would not be see from the main auditorium.

Answer (score 1):

In 19th century theatres, the *avant-loge* was the box closest to the stage, the “front box” if you will. The word seems to have fallen out of use, but it was adopted into other languages and used in Russia, Scandinavia and probably other countries well into the 20th century.

In Russia, a number of larger theatres such as the Bolshoi and the Kyiv Opera House (which I believe is the one referred to here) had an imperial box at the back, as seen in this painting from the Bolshoi.

[image: Mihály Zichy (1827–1906), “Performance in the Bolshoi Theatre”, 1856]
*Mihály Zichy (1827–1906), “Performance in the Bolshoi Theatre”, 1856*

There was then also a set of *avant-loges* next to the stage, as seen in the below image, which shows the interior of the Kyiv Opera House.

[image]

The Czar and his entourage would have been moved from the imperial box to avoid being hurt or killed by the gun-wielding assassin, and as a generally prescribed precaution. Quite likely, one or more of the *avant-loges* were kept empty for this exact purpose whenever the Czar was in attendance, and were presumably chosen because they were the places in the house where people could be brought to safety most expediently in case of an emergency. While not completely secure, they at least had curtains and could be protected more easily.

Comment: I like how in _Performance in the Bolshoï theatre_ picture, clearly the performance is not on the stage, but rather in the loges.

Comment: Thank you @Segorian for your thorough and beautifully-illustrated answer.